# Problems with Pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN

Tags: pygame

I'm a beginner to python & Pygame (& all coding!). I have defined an interactive button

```
def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action=None):

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:

        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x, y, w, h))
        smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 25)
        textSurf = smallText.render(msg, True, black)
        textRect = textSurf.get_rect()
        textRect.center = ( (x + (w/2)), (y + ( h/2)))
        gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and action != None:

            action()


    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x, y, w, h))

        smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 25)
        textSurf = smallText.render(msg, True, black)
        textRect = textSurf.get_rect()
        textRect.center = ( (x + (w/2)), (y + ( h/2)))
        gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)
```

When I call the button from my intro screen all works fine

```
global gameDisplay
intro = True

while intro:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((1060,800))
    pygame.display.set_caption ("Maze")

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 115)
    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 50)

    TextSurf = largeText.render("Monster Mazes", True, black)
    TextRect = TextSurf.get_rect()
    TextRect.center = ((1060/2), (800/3))

    TextSurf1 = smallText.render("Collect the food & drink before boarding the spaceship", True, black)
    TextRect1 = TextSurf1.get_rect()
    TextRect1.center = ((1060/2), (800/3*2))


    TextSurf2 = smallText.render("Don't hit the walls!", True, black)
    TextRect2 = TextSurf2.get_rect()
    TextRect2.center = ((1060/2), ((800/3*2)+100))

    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf1, TextRect1)
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf2, TextRect2)

    button("Go!", 200, 400, 100, 50, green, bright_green, set_maze)
    button("Quit", 760, 400, 100, 50, red, bright_red, quitgame)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)
```

However, when I call it from my game over screen it acts as though the mouse button is always pressed, so as soon as the cursor hovers over the button the action is called even though the mouse button isn't clicked

```
def game_over():

    global score
    global lives
    global width
    global height
    global maze
    global gameDisplay

    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        bonus_score = lives*50
        total_score = score + bonus_score

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 115)
        smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 50)
        TextSurf = largeText.render("Game Over!", True, black)
        TextRect = TextSurf.get_rect()
        TextRect.center = ((width/2), (height/3))

        TextSurfScore = smallText.render("Score : " + str(score), True, black)
        TextRectScore = TextSurfScore.get_rect()
        TextRectScore.center = ((width/2), (height/3*2))

        TextSurfScoreBonus = smallText.render("Bonus : " + str(bonus_score), True, black)
        TextRectScoreBonus = TextSurfScoreBonus.get_rect()
        TextRectScoreBonus.center = ((width/2), (height/3*2)+50)

        TextSurfScoreTotal = smallText.render("Total : " + str(total_score), True, black)
        TextRectScoreTotal = TextSurfScoreTotal.get_rect()
        TextRectScoreTotal.center = ((width/2), (height/3*2)+100)

        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurfScore, TextRectScore)
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurfScoreBonus, TextRectScoreBonus)
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurfScoreTotal, TextRectScoreTotal)

        button("Play again", 200, 400, 100, 50, green, bright_green, play_again)
        button("Quit", 760, 400, 100, 50, red, bright_red, quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)
```

I can't see what I have done wrong / differently !!! I'd really appreciate any help!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you have no variable called event so in the line

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN
```

event doesnt exist. so it goes to the for loop

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
```

which would be mousbuttondown or something else, its not reliable

this is an easy fix

```py
click = False  #have a variable called click
while True:

    click = False every frame, reset it back to false
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            click = True  #check if user clicked
```

```py
 if click and action != None:
```

Im not 100% sure about reason but solution should work. If you are getting an error, you can send it as a argument

```
def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, click,action=None):
    ...


button("Play again", 200, 400, 100, 50, green, bright_green, click, play_again)
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this for me. Although your solution didn't seem to work, it did help me see where the problem was - you mentioned the variable 'event' & when I realised that the difference between the times I was calling the button was that game over was a function I realised that the variable 'event' needed to be global.

Comment: @Louise Sorry my solution didnt help. Thought passing click as an argument wouldbe solved that issue but apparently not. Glad you found a solution tho

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution! Game over is a function, but the intro is not. I just needed to Global event & it now works.